# Missing required parameter for route although parameter is passed in view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-6

I got error like this:

> Missing required parameters for [Route: resumenes.show] [URI:
>   resumenes/{resumen}]. (View:
>   .../resources/views/resumenes/index.blade.php)

**Controller**

```
public function index()
{
    $resumenes = Resumene::orderBy('title','ASC')->paginate();
    return view('resumenes.index', compact('resumenes') );
}

public function show(Resumene $resumen)
{

    return view('resumenes.show', [
        'resumen'=> $resumen
    ]);
}
```

**Routes**

```
 Route::get('/resumenes/{resumen}', 'ResumeneController@show')->name('resumenes.show');
```

**INDEX.BLADE.PHP** In this view is where it shows me an error

```
 @extends('layout')
 @section('title')
 Mis Resumenes
 @endsection

@section('content')
<h1>Mis Resumenes</h1>

@include('partials.sessions')

<a href="{{ route('resumenes.create') }}">Nuevo Resumen</a>
<ul>
    @forelse($resumenes as $resumen)
    <h2>{{ $resumen->title }}</h2>
            **<li><a href="{{ route('resumenes.show', $resumen) }}" ><button>Ir</button></a>** 
            <br> Creado hace {{ $resumen->created_at->diffForHumans() }} </li>
            <hr>
    @empty
            <li>No hay proyectos existentes</li>
    @endforelse
{{ $resumenes->links() }}
</ul>
 @endsection
```

*The error supposed to be* in

```
   <li><a href="{{ route('resumenes.show', $resumen) }}" ><button>Ir</button></a>
```

Comment: change public function show(Resumene $resumen) to public function show($resumen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at code you provided everything seems to be fine.

You should try:

```
php artisan view:clear
```

to make sure old view is not used.

If it won't help, you should run:

```
php artisan route:list
```

to make sure url for this route really looks like `/resumenes/{resumen}` because route definittion might be a more complex (using route grouping) so the full url might look like this: `/something/{something}/resumenes/{resumen}`

Comment: Hi Marcin Nabialek, I've just solved it by turning resume paremeter into an optional parameter, {resumen} -> {resumen?}. That was the solution I found, thanks for your help!

Comment: @Juan.  Your suggestion has been very helpful.  Thanks very much!  I had put a post about this issue I am facing with Laravel 6.3.