# Missing required parameters for [Route: projects.edit] [URI: projects/{project}/edit] Laravel 6.3

Tags: laravel-6

This error has blocked me way forward. Does anyone have a solution to the Missing required parameters error?  I have a very simple CRUD setup which throws this error in the Controller 'edit' method.  This happens when the request is forwarded to the edit view.

**Error:**

````
```Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
Missing required parameters for [Route: projects.edit] [URI: 
projects/{project}/edit]. (View: 
T:\estie\resources\views\frontend\layouts\homeapp.blade.php)```
````

**Route definition is:**

````
```Route::resource('projects','ProjectsController');```
````

**Controller Edit method:**

````
```public function edit(Project $project)
    {
        return view('projects.edit')  ->with('project',$project);    
    }```
````

**This is part of my index.blade.php which extends homeapp.blade.php:**

```
<td align="center">
       <a href="{{ route('projects.edit', ['project' => $project]) }}">EDIT</a>
</td>
```

Appreciate any help, please.

Comment: what is the value of project variable in view?? it seems null.

Answer (score 0):

This error is thrown when you try to get the URL of a route using the `route` function without providing a required parameter.

Look for the `route('projects.edit')` call in your `homeapp.blade.php` and add the project as a parameter: `route('projects.edit', ['project' => $project])`

Comment: Thanks nXu.  My index.blade.php extends homeapp.blade.php. I have updated the URL route in the post.  It is in the same way you mentioned.

Comment: I got a workaround from a response by @Juan Olivera.  The solution he suggested is to make the parameter optional in the route definition '/projects/{project?}/edit'.  Not sure whether this is recommended.  Util I get a better one, this seems to be a work around.  The related post is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59472170/missing-required-parameter-for-route-although-parameter-is-passed-in-view?rq=1